# Mulitiple dovecot.conf files. Which is the actual configuration file?

Tags: dovecot

I needed to make changes to dovecot.conf.  However, there are 2 of them on my system -- similar, but different:

`/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf`

`/usr/share/dovecot/dovecot.conf`

What's up?  Which is the actual config file?  Are they both being used?

Thanks.

Comment: In all likelihood, I'd guess the one in `/usr/share` is either an example, or a base config file which is copied to `/etc` during the installation process with modifications based on selections by the admin. Check the postinst file of the package.

Comment: Will-do.  Thanks.